# Convert JSF calendar date into JodaTime in Converter

Tags: jsf-2, converters

JodaTime is amicably the best date and time library out there, maybe.

So I am tempted to receive user input from the front end xhtml Calendar widget in JodaTime instance at the backing bean. Therefore I am thinking of using JSF Converter for this job.

Is this wise to do?

At the same time, since I'm using Primefaces component library and I am already receiving a Date object at my backing bean, would providing a custom Converter require me to do this all over again? I.e. convert from String format to Date object, then to JodaTime DateTime object. Can I somehow let the default JSF convert it to Date first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just stick to `java.util.Date` in the model, view and persistence layer (as all have already builtin support for it and you generally don't need to perform date calculations/manipulations at those layers at all) and use JodaTime in business layer only whenever you need to perform calculations/manipulations based on the `java.util.Date` value. This will keep a lot of things simple.

Once you're on Java 8, migrate `java.util.Date` to [`java.time.Local`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)/[`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). JSF 2.3 will ship with additional Java 8 support in `<f:convertDateTime>`. Until then, you'll need to homebrew them as instructed in this answer: [How to use java.time.ZonedDateTime / LocalDateTime in p:calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883270/how-to-use-java-time-zoneddatetime-localdatetime-in-pcalendar/).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful share BalusC

Comment: Be aware of the Java January being 0 and Joda January being 1. In Java API they start the month counting from 0 ...

Comment: This is only the case when you use the epic `java.util.Calendar` class. **Nothing** in the question suggests this is actually being used. The only "calendar" term applies to the `<p:calendar>` component/widget which by itself already defaults to a `java.util.Date` model value.